# How to find the total price of clothes in the dictionary in given situation?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, tuples, price

How can I find the total price of clothes if a python dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    1: ['Shirt', ' Dior', 16, ' $1500'], 
    2: ['Skirt', ' Chanel', ' 13', '$ 500'], 
    3: ['Scarf', ' LV', ' 2', ' $500'], 
    4: ['Pants', 'Gucci', ' 10', '$200'], 
    5: ['Coat', 'Armani', ' 8', '$6000']
}
```

Comment: how do you compute price? 16* 1500$ + 13*500$ + ...?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use `re` in order to extract the price

```
import re
data = {1: ['Shirt', ' Dior', 16, ' $1500'], 2: ['Skirt', ' Chanel', ' 13', '$ 500'],
        3: ['Scarf', ' LV', ' 2', ' $500'], 4: ['Pants', 'Gucci', ' 10', '$200'], 5: ['Coat', 'Armani', ' 8', '$6000']}

price = 0
for v in data.values():
        temp = v[-1].strip()
        price += int(re.findall(r'\d+',temp)[0])
print(f'Total price: ${price}')
```

output

```
Total price: $8700
```

if the entry before the last one (16,13,etc) is the number of items and we need to multiple it - the below takes care of that

```
import re
data = {1: ['Shirt', ' Dior', 16, ' $1500'], 2: ['Skirt', ' Chanel', ' 13', '$ 500'],
        3: ['Scarf', ' LV', ' 2', ' $500'], 4: ['Pants', 'Gucci', ' 10', '$200'], 5: ['Coat', 'Armani', ' 8', '$6000']}

price = 0
for v in data.values():
        temp_price = v[-1].strip()
        cnt = v[-2]
        if isinstance(cnt,str):
                cnt = int(cnt.strip())
        price += (int(re.findall(r'\d+', temp_price)[0]) * cnt)
print(f'Total price: ${price}')
```

output

```
Total price: $81500
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not clear that if you want to have by each type or overall sum.

You could do the following if you are willing to based on the type using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
   c =  {
        1: ['Shirt', ' Dior', 16, ' $1500'], 
        2: ['Skirt', ' Chanel', 13, '$500'], 
        3: ['Scarf', ' LV', 2, ' $500'], 
        4: ['Pants', 'Gucci', 10, '$200'], 
        5: ['Coat', 'Armani',  8, '$6000']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(c).T
df = df.rename(columns={0:"type",1:"brand",2:"quantities",3: "price"})
df["price_clean"]  = df["price"].apply(lambda x: int(x.split("$")[1]))
df["total"] = df["quantities"] * df["price_clean"]
```

To calculate the total sum now do this : `df.total.sum()`

Comment: If this answers your question properly then please accept my answer